# Create separate file per class from a wsdl?

Tags: c#-4.0, wsdl, svcutil.exe, xsd.exe

A company I am working with has created a wsdl of how they would LIKE the WCF service interface I am about to write to look.  Thats not really a problem as its just a starting point rather than a proscription.

However, is it possible from their wsdl to create individual class files for each class in the interface?

e.g. instead of create the proxy class, do the hard work for me ;) and create the individual classes themselves?

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much...was hoping for an undocumented switch which was "create as separate files" :(

Comment: @Alpay: please make this the answer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can generate the *proxy class* in normal ways via [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and then, copy and paste the generated code into your seperate class files. This way, it will be simpler to constitute the classes you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. As long as you have downloaded the WSDL document. You can use [XSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to generate proxy classes from the definition.

Cheers.

Comment: This creates a single file and not a file per class